# How to use the wso2 esb connector

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a question regarding to how to use the wso2 esb connector. I have just followed these steps: http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Using+a+Connector to get more information. Then I checked out the sample connector from: https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/distribution/foo-connector to build and try to run this sample. After deploying successfully, I don't know how to use it. ESB. I am using wso2 esb 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

Download the connector zip file from https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/distribution

Add and enable connector as described in http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Managing+Connectors+in+Your+ESB+Instance

> To add a connector:
>
> On the Main tab in the ESB Management Console, under Connectors click Add.
>   Click Browse, specify the ZIP file, and click Open.
>   Click Upload.
>
> The connector will now appear in the Connectors list and is ready to
>   be enabled in your ESB instance.
>
> To enable a connector:
>
> On the Main tab in the ESB Management Console, under Connectors click List to view your uploaded connectors.
>   Click Enable next to a connector you want to enable, and then confirm that you want to change its status. Repeat this step for each
>   connector you want to enable.

Use the connector as described in the doc (eg. [Twitter Connector](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Twitter+Connector)) within your ESB configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the missing steps are to add a proxy to use connector, and visit the proxy to invoke the connector.